# Regex to FAX Numbers from string

Tags: android, ios, regex

I'm tring to find fax number from below regex but it does not work with `Fax: (91-44) 7781 1234` or `FAX: +91 44 7781 1234 / 2828 1111`

```
(?<=FAX[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)|(?<=F[:\\s])([+\\d\\s]+\\S)(?=\\s\\D)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the given numbers you could use:

```
"(?i)fax\\s*\\:\\s*\\+?[/\\(\\d\\)\\s-]+\\d"
```